# How to add prefix ('/admin') to URL routes in Angular 7

Tags: angular, routes

I have routes defined in Angular 7 as

```
 {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path: 'header', component: HeaderComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: 'footer', component: FooterComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: 'manage-customer', component: ManageCustomerComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: 'view-customer', component: ViewCustomerComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: 'add-merchant', component: AddMerchantsComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: 'edit-merchant/:id', component: EditMerchantsComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: 'manage-merchant', component: ManageMerchantsComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: 'view-merchant/:id', component: ViewMerchantsComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
```

and i want to add '/admin' to all the URLs so that it becomes like

`{path: '/admin/register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path: '/admin/header', component: HeaderComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: '/admin/footer', component: FooterComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: '/admin/manage-customer', component: ManageCustomerComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: '/admin/view-customer', component: ViewCustomerComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: '/admin/add-merchant', component: AddMerchantsComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: '/admin/edit-merchant/:id', component: EditMerchantsComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: '/admin/manage-merchant', component: ManageMerchantsComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: '/admin/view-merchant/:id', component: ViewMerchantsComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},`

I tried adding children routes to /admin main routes but it was throwing error. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `{ path: 'booking', component: BookingComponent, children: [
        { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
      ] },`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an admin parent component and put  to that. And then put all the existing Routes inside children of the parent component.

```
  {path: 'home', component: FrontHomeComponent},

  {
    path:'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    children:[
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path: 'header', component: HeaderComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: 'footer', component: FooterComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: 'manage-customer', component: ManageCustomerComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: 'view-customer', component: ViewCustomerComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
    ]
  },
```

This should do the work.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was missing <router-outlet> in Parent component.

Answer (score -1):

You can use it as children of admin route

```
{
path:  'admin',
component:  AdminComponent,
children: [
{path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path: 'header', component: HeaderComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: 'footer', component: FooterComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: 'manage-customer', component: ManageCustomerComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: 'view-customer', component: ViewCustomerComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: 'add-merchant', component: AddMerchantsComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: 'edit-merchant/:id', component: EditMerchantsComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: 'manage-merchant', component: ManageMerchantsComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: 'view-merchant/:id', component: ViewMerchantsComponent, canActivate:  [AuthGuardService]}
]
}
```